# Parse bool from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, boolean

I am trying to parse the multiple bool values. In below code *JSONObject* is the `NSMutableArray.ii` is the indexpath. But with the below am getting only one value. This is first time to me handling bool values from json, help me to fetch the bool values inside the answer list array.

```
 BOOL options= [[[jsonObject objectAtIndex:ii] objectForKey:@"Is_Correct"]boolValue] ;
 NSLog(@"correct answer %d",options);
```

[image: JSON]

Comment: is `jsonObject` contains `AnswersList` array?

Comment: yes, am getting the bool value but only the top bool am gettng

Comment: How can you access a key value pair from an array? [jsonObject objectAtIndex:ii] will return an array then you can not use method objectForKey: for an array it will return nothing.

Comment: Don't do long chain polymer statements, especially when you don't quite know what you're doing.  Fetch `jsonObject[1]`, then `["AnswersList"]`, then `[0]`, then `["Is_Correct"]` as separate statements.  (And you probably want to iterate over the arrays.)

Comment: (Everyone below is completely skipping over AnswersList.)

Comment: @iDeveloper -- If you read the JSON correctly (I agree the presentation is confusing), you will see that `jsonObject` is an array of "objects".  The "objects", in turn, contain arrays for "AnswersList", and the arrays contain "objects" with the leaf-level data.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary* outerArrayElement = jsonObject[1];
NSArray* amswersList = outerArrayElement["AnswersList"];
NSDictionary* innerArrayElement = answersList[0];
NSNumber* is_correctNum = innerArrayElement["Is_Correct"];
BOOL is_correct = [is_correctNum].boolValue;
```

But one should iterate over the arrays, and also check for nil results in some cases, especially when retrieving the outer array element.

And for testing insert NSLog statements after each step.